# How to install bower component with git submodules as a dependency?

Tags: npm, package, bower, frontend

I have a library which requires 2 dependencies to exist in the "vendor" directory. This library has these 2 dependencies installed as git submodules on Github, so to install my library from a Git clone you would do:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/MYLIBRARY.git
```

And to install it as another Git submodule, you would do:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/MYLIBRARY.git && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

The issue comes when trying to install it with Bower, as the Git submodules do not get downloaded with the bower package (the dependency folders exist, but are empty). The 2 dependencies exist separately on bower, but as they are required to be in the "vendor" directory of the main library, I cannot include them as bower dependencies. I also can't assume that any project installing my library will be a Git repo, so I can't do something like:

```
bower install MYLIBRARY && git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Which would work if the parent project you installed my library in was a Git repo, but would error if not.

I'm worried I may have to have an instruction similar to:

```
bower install MYLIBRARY && cd bower_componets/MYLIBRARY && git clone https://github.com/DEPENDENCY1.git vendor/DEPENDENCY1 && git clone https://github.com/DEPENDENCY2.git vendor/DEPENDENCY2
```

This can be tidied slightly by adding an npm run script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "bower_vendor": "git clone https://github.com/DEPENDENCY1.git vendor/DEPENDENCY1 && git clone https://github.com/DEPENDENCY2.git vendor/DEPENDENCY2"
}
```

Then the installation instruction would become:

```
bower install MYLIBRARY && cd bower_componets/MYLIBRARY && npm run bower_vendor
```

Which is a little neater, but again wouldn't work if the user has customised their `bower_components` directory (which is simple enough to change in the above command, but is still another concern).

I'm hoping I've just missed something somewhere which will solve my issue. I read that bower performs a `git clone` of the repo, so if there was a way to get it to perform `git clone --recursive` that would be amazing.

Thanks